# New remote desktop application using powershell in C# - Parameter

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-desktop

Using `System.Management.Automation` I tried adding a new remote desktop application in C#.

```
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("new-item -path RDS:\\RemoteApp\\RemoteAppPrograms -name         ‘calc2’ -ApplicationPath \"%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe\"");
```

Above is the code I used to create the application. However it throws a

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException:
  A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ApplicationPath'.
```

My guess is new-item cmdlet does not have a ApplicationPath parameter. So C# throws a error. Although this works fine in Powershell prompt.

Any solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `New-Item` cmdlet has a `Name` parameter but not an `ApplicationPath` parameter which is why you're getting that error.  New-Item is used to create empty new items like an empty file or directory (on the FileSystem provider at least).  Are you trying to create a shortcut?  For a shortcut try something like this:

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("RDS:\\RemoteApp\\RemoteAppPrograms\\calc2.lnk")
$lnk.TargetPath = "\"$env:WINDIR\\system32\\calc.exe\""
$lnk.Save()
```

In this case, the problem was a custom provider was providing the ApplicationPath dynamic parameter.  The OP thought they were loading the associated module but apparently the module was installed for a 64-bit process and the hosting C# exe was compiled as x86 (32-bit).  Once the module was made available to 32-bit PowerShell the issue was resolved.

Comment: Yes, that was my guess. But when creating a remote app in RDS it requires the `ApplicationPath` parameter. If you enter the command in powershell without `ApplicationPath` parameter it will prompt you to provide the value.

Comment: Ah so it sounds like RDS is an 3rd party provider. In that case, you  need to get that provider loaded into the Powershell runspace you're using in C#.  How do you load it from the command line? Is this an import-module or add-pssnapin?  You could test this by executing "Get-PSDrive" as the command in C# and then look at the results to see if the RDS drive is already created or not.

Comment: Its using `RemoteDesktopServices` module. I tried loading it using
`InitialSessionState initialSession = initialSessionState.CreateDefault();  
initialSession.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "RemoteDesktopServices" });  
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession);  
runspace.Open();`  
but it results in same result!

Comment: I managed to get it running. Seems to be C# is starting a x86 powershell instance where necessary dlls are not loaded. When I copied the relevant dlls it worked. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I updated the answer to reflect your findings.